# Cross Domain Modules with Require.js not adding ".js" for submodules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having trouble getting cross domain modules to work in require.js

I have a submodule on othersite.com

```
// othersite.com/js/submodule.js
define(function() {
   return { test: "Submodule here!" };
});
```

And a module on othersite.com that uses that submodule

```
// othersite.com/js/mainmodule.js
define(['./submodule'], function(SubModule) {
  return {
    test: "Main Module Here" + SubModule.test,
  };
});
```

Now on mainsite.com I have a module that tries to reference mainmodule on othersite.com.

```
// mainsite.com/js/app.js
requirejs([
    './somelocalmodule',
    './someotherlocalmodule',
    'http://othersite.com:1234/js/mainmodule.js',
  ], function(
    SomeLocalModule,
    SomeOtherLocalModule,
    MainModule) {
  console.log("test: " + MainModule.test);
});
```

The problem is when require.js tries to load submodule.js it fails because it combines the URL from mainmodule.js. So `./submodule` becomes `http://othersite.com:1234/js/submodule`. Then the code in require.js checks that URL, sees it has a colon in it, decides not to add the `.js` and tries to load `http://othersite.com:1234/js/submodule` which of course without the `.js` does not exist which means it fails to load `submodule.js`

I can add `.js` to `./submodule` in mainmodule.js but that kind of defeats the whole point which is that if I've got some large set of files using require.js in the recommended way without the `.js` suffixes and then I try to reference those cross domain I'd have to go change all the files on otherdomain.com to be non-standard.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get require.js to handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a config path fixed this for me

In my html

```
<script data-main="/js/app.js" src="/js/require.js"></script>
<script>
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    othersite: '//othersite.com:1234',
  },
});
</script>
```

Then in mainsite.com/js/app.js

```
// mainsite.com/js/app.js
requirejs([
    './somelocalmodule',
    './someotherlocalmodule',
    'othersite/js/mainmodule.js',
  ], function(
    SomeLocalModule,
    SomeOtherLocalModule,
    MainModule) {
  console.log("test: " + MainModule.test);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar challenge recently, found [Loading Modules from Packages](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages) pretty usefull.

Example:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        source1: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ractive/0.7.3',
        source2: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.0.0',
        source3: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.0.0',
        lodash: 'lodash.min',
        ractive: 'ractive.min',
        jquery: 'jquery.min'
    }
});

require.config({
    baseUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/'
});
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    print('jQuery version ' + $.fn.jquery);
});

require(['source1/ractive'], function(ractive) {
    console.debug('Ractive version ' + ractive.VERSION);
});

require(['source2/lodash'], function(_) {
    console.debug('Lodash version ' + _.VERSION);
});

require(['source3/lodash'], function(_) {
    console.debug('Lodash version ' + _.VERSION);
});
```

Will output:

```
jQuery version 2.0.0
Lodash version 3.0.0
Lodash version 2.0.0
Ractive version 0.7.3
```

[See JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/xasiya/edit?js,output)